# categorizing a new variable based on two conditions and multiple levels per condition

Tags: r

I am trying to recode a race/ethnicity variable derived from a `Hispanic` variable and a 6 other `race` variables.

I've tried some of these [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492503/how-to-combine-multiple-data-frame-columns-in-r). I can't quite figure out how to keep all my different levels for each factor.

The `Hispanic` variable has 5 levels: `0:NA, 1:yes, 2:no, 3:unable to determine, 99:missing`.

Each `race` variable has 3 levels: `0:does not apply, 1:applies, 99:missing`.

My new `p1raceeth` variable will have 7 levels: `0:Unknown, 1:Black,NH, 2:Hispanic any race, 3:Other, 4:White,NH, 99:missing`.

I had tried also coding it with the code below and it works for the one `race:amakn` variable but then when I move on the the next `race` variable with the same code it overwrites the past recode. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Including suggestions on how to collapse the factor levels within the `race` and `Hispanic` variables to make this more manageable.

What prompted this was I was trying to combine `asian` with `nhopi`. Quite the rabbit hole.

```
d_a$p1raceeth <- "0"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="0" & d_a$amakn=="0"] <- "0"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="0" & d_a$amakn=="1"] <- "0"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="0" & d_a$amakn=="99"] <- "0"

d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="1" & d_a$amakn=="0"] <- "2"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="1" & d_a$amakn=="1"] <- "2"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="1" & d_a$amakn=="99"] <- "99"

d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="2" & d_a$amakn=="0"] <- "99"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="2" & d_a$amakn=="1"] <- "3"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="2" & d_a$amakn=="99"] <- "99"

d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="3" & d_a$amakn=="0"] <- "0"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="3" & d_a$amakn=="1"] <- "3"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="3" & d_a$amakn=="99"] <- "99"

d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="99" & d_a$amakn=="0"] <- "99"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="99" & d_a$amakn=="1"] <- "3"
d_a$p1raceeth[d_a$Hispanic=="99" & d_a$amakn=="99"] <- "99"
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
df <- read.table(text=
"Hispanic amakn asian blkaa nhopi white utod
1           1          0          0          0          0          1         0
2           2         99         99          1         99         99        99
3          99         99         99         99         99         99        99
4           3         99         99         99         99         99        99
5           0         99         99         99         99         99        99
6          99         99         99         99         99         99        99
7           3         99         99         99         99         99        99
8           0         99         99         99         99         99        99
9           2          0          0          0          0          1         0
10          2          0          0          0          0          1         0
11          2          0          0          0          0          1         0
12          1          0          0          0          0          1         0
13          0         99         99         99         99         99        99
14          2          0          0          0          0          1         0
15          0         99         99         99         99         99        99
16          2          0          0          0          0          1         0
17          2          0          0          1          0          0         0
18          0          0          0          0          0          0         0
19         99         99         99         99         99         99        99
20          1         99         99         99         99         99        99
21          0         99         99         99         99         99        99
22          2          0          0          0          0          1         0
23          2          0          0          0          0          1         0
24          2          0          0          1          0          0         0
25          0         99         99         99         99         99        99
26         99          0          0          0          0          1         0
27          0         99         99         99         99         99        99
28         99          0          0          0          0          1         0
29          1         99         99         99         99         99        99
30         99         99         99         99         99         99        99
31          2          0          0          0          0          1         0
32          2          0          0          0          0          1         0
33          3          0          1          0          0          0         0
34          2         99         99         99         99          1        99
35          2          0          0          0          0          1         0
36          1         99         99         99         99         99        99
37          0         99         99         99         99         99        99
38          2          0          0          0          0          1         0
39         99         99         99         99         99         99        99
40          1         99         99         99         99         99        99
", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to code missings as `NA` which makes life easier.

```
d_a[] <- lapply(d_a, function(x) {x[x %in% 99] <- NA;x})
d_a$Hispanic[d_a$Hispanic %in% 0] <- NA
```

Then, using `within`, we go through the options one by one.

1. Create index variable `mis` that identifies rows where all
   race variables are `NA`.
2. Span an empty `p1raceeth` variable with all `NA`.
3. Where `Hispanic` isn't `NA` and `rowSums` of other variables
   are zero we set `"unknown"`.
4. Where `Hispanic` is `1` and others are not in `mis`, we have
   `"Hispanic any race"`. `Hispanic` in `2` or `3` accordingly.
5. Set `"White"`, where `white` is in `1`, `"Black"`
   accordingly.
6. It might be, that there are more than one race variables with the value `1`, we might want to set those `p1raceeth` to `NA` (or something else), identifiable where `rowSums` w/o `"Hispanic"` are greater than `1`.
7. (If we want to, we set all `NA` to `"missing"`, but I don't
   recommend this, since it would delete the information that it's
   `NA`, so I've commented it out.)
8. Finally, we `rm`ove the `mis` variable, to not to appear in the result.

```
res <- within(d_a, {
  mis <- apply(d_a[-1], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
  p1raceeth <- NA
  p1raceeth[is.na(Hispanic) & rowSums(d_a[-1]) %in% 0] <- "unknown"
  p1raceeth[Hispanic %in% 1 & !mis] <- "Hispanic any race"
  p1raceeth[Hispanic %in% 2:3 & !mis] <- "Other"
  p1raceeth[Hispanic %in% 2 & white %in% 1] <- "White"
  p1raceeth[Hispanic %in% 2 & blkaa %in% 1] <- "Black"
  p1raceeth[rowSums(d_a[-1], na.rm=T) > 1] <- NA
  # p1raceeth[is.na(p1raceeth)] <- "missing"
  rm(mis)
})
```

*Notice,* that I used `%in%` here instead of (the probably more familiar) `==`. That's important since `==` occasionally yields `NA` which we don't want here, whereas `%in%` doesn't.

If you need a 'factor' variable, you could optionally do now as a last step:

```
res$p1raceeth <- as.factor(res$p1raceeth)
```

### Result

I show the unique rows of `res`ult, ordered by `Hispanic`.

```
unique(res[order(res$Hispanic), ])
#    Hispanic amakn asian blkaa nhopi white utod         p1raceeth
# 1         1     0     0     0     0     1    0 Hispanic any race
# 20        1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA              <NA>
# 2         2    NA    NA     1    NA    NA   NA             Black
# 9         2     0     0     0     0     1    0             White
# 17        2     0     0     1     0     0    0             Black
# 34        2    NA    NA    NA    NA     1   NA             White
# 4         3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA              <NA>
# 33        3     0     1     0     0     0    0             Other
# 3        NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA              <NA>
# 18       NA     0     0     0     0     0    0           unknown
# 26       NA     0     0     0     0     1    0              <NA>
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, you can use `ifelse`/`case_when` and combine the conditions using `%in%` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(p1raceeth = case_when(Hispanic== 0 & amakn %in% c(0, 1, 99) ~ 0, 
                               Hispanic== 1 & amakn %in% c(0, 1) ~ 2, 
                               Hispanic %in% c(2, 3) & amakn == 1 ~ 3,
                               Hispanic == 3 & amakn == 0 ~ 0,
                               Hispanic == 99 & amakn == 1~ 3,
                               TRUE ~ 99))
```